# How to concatenate bits to varbinary with CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

I have a table with IDs and Bits in the following Order:

```
ID  Bit
1   0
1   0
1   1
1   0
1   0
1   0
1   1
1   0
1   1
1   0
1   ...
... ...
2   0
2   1
2   0
2   0
2   1
2   0
2   0
2   0
2   1
2   0
2   ...
... ...
n   ...
```

How to group the ID column and concatenate the Bit column to a varbinary column using CTE?

```
ID  Bits
1   0x...
2   0x...
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: First of all you have to be aware, that there is not inherent sort order in your table. Any solution someone might offer could produce random results. You MUST add a column 'Position' (or similar) to your table! With this I'll provide an exampel soon.

Comment: Could you flesh out the example results a _bit_? It's not obvious what you expect regarding MSB/LSB, how to handle bits that don't occur in multiples of 8, ... .

Comment: Is the upper limit on the number of bits with the same `ID` less than 64? That would make it easy to combine the values into a `BIGINT` and then shuffle it to a `VARBINARY`.

Comment: For each ID there can be up to 1920 bits. So I need a varbinary of max. 240 bytes.

Comment: @Shnugo: You're right. I need a position column. I have an order column, but I didn't write it down, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @Bits as Table ( Id Int, Position Int, Value Int );
insert into @Bits ( Id, Position, Value ) values
  ( 1, 0, 1 ), ( 1, 1, 1 ), ( 1, 2, 0 ), ( 1, 3, 1 ),
  ( 1, 4, 1 ), ( 1, 5, 1 ), ( 1, 6, 1 ), ( 1, 7, 0 ),
  ( 1, 8, 1 ), ( 1, 9, 0 ), ( 1, 10, 1 ), ( 1, 11, 0 ),
  ( 1, 12, 1 ), ( 1, 13, 1 ), ( 1, 14, 0 ), ( 1, 15, 1 ),
  ( 1, 16, 1 ), ( 1, 17, 0 ), ( 1, 18, 1 ), ( 1, 19, 1 ),
  ( 1, 20, 1 ), ( 1, 21, 1 ), ( 1, 22, 1 ), ( 1, 23, 0 ),
  ( 1, 24, 1 ), ( 1, 25, 1 ), ( 1, 26, 1 ), ( 1, 27, 0 ),
  ( 1, 28, 1 ), ( 1, 29, 1 ), ( 1, 30, 1 ), ( 1, 31, 1 ),
  ( 2, 0, 0 ), ( 2, 1, 1 ), ( 2, 2, 0 ), ( 2, 3, 0 ),
  ( 2, 4, 0 ), ( 2, 5, 0 ), ( 2, 6, 1 ), ( 2, 7, 0 );

select * from @Bits order by Id, Position;

with ExtendedBits as (
  select Id, Position, Value, Position / 4 as NibbleId, Power( 2, 3 - Position % 4 ) * Value as Mask
    from @Bits ),
  Nibbles as (
  select Id, NibbleId, Sum( Mask ) as Nibble
    from ExtendedBits
    group by Id, NibbleId ),
  HexStrings as (
  select Id, Stuff( ( select Substring( '0123456789ABCDEF', Nibble + 1, 1 ) from Nibbles where Id = N.Id order by NibbleId for XML Path( '' ) ), 1, 0, '' ) as HexString
    from Nibbles as N
    group by Id )
  select Id, Cast( '' as xml).value('xs:hexBinary( substring(sql:column("HexString"), 0) )', 'varbinary(max)') as VarBin
    from HexStrings;
```

Note that you can view the intermediate results by replacing the final `SELECT` with `select * from ExtendedBits` or `Nibbles` or `HexStrings`. A handy debugging technique.

Comment: Some Hexstrings return NULL for the VarBin column using Cast( '' as xml).value('xs:hexBinary( substring(sql:column("HexString"), 0) )', 'varbinary(max)'), for example "6896A2A62AA869A49A82A4AAA2AA8AAA2AA8AAA2A91A586A89A91A91A68AAA2AA2AA88286AA4AA4AA8AAA2AA86A8668AAA4A68A68AAA1698AA869A2AA2080AA8AA8AA4AA2A68AAA26A2AA2028A98AAA29A00001AAA2A626A02AA8A945A62AA28AA510000000000000000000000000000000000000000000". Don't know why :(

Comment: I've lost 1 Nibble, because my bit data has one bit value of 2. So I got a Mask greater 15 and the substring returns an empty string. It's my fault using incorrect data... ;)

Comment: Since SQL Server 2008, you can use "convert(varbinary(max), HexString, 2) as VarBin"

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
declare @bits TABLE(ID INT, myBit BIT, Position INT);
insert into @bits values(1,0,0)
                       ,(1,0,1)
                       ,(1,1,2)
                       ,(1,0,3)
                       ,(1,0,4)
                       ,(1,0,5)
                       ,(1,1,6)
                       ,(1,0,7)
                       ,(1,1,8)
                       ,(1,0,9)

                       ,(2,0,0)
                       ,(2,1,1)
                       ,(2,0,2)
                       ,(2,0,3)
                       ,(2,1,4)
                       ,(2,0,5)
                       ,(2,0,6)
                       ,(2,0,7)
                       ,(2,1,8)
                       ,(2,0,9);
WITH myIDs AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ID
    FROM @bits
)
SELECT '0x' + concatenatedBits.string
FROM myIDs
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT
    (
    SELECT CAST(myBit AS VARCHAR(1))
    FROM @bits AS b
    WHERE b.ID=myIDs.ID
    ORDER BY Position
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
    ).value('.','varchar(max)')
) AS concatenatedBits(string)
```

Comment: @HABO, what do you mean? It will just create a string of the zeros and ones given in the table in the given order,starting with "0x". As many as you want... The OP did not state clearly what he is going to do with this...

Comment: Well, a VARCHAR like "0x00000100" can easily be converted to VARBINARY with CONVERT(VARBINARY,'0x0000000000000100',1), but attention, the count of "digits" must be divided by four

Comment: Your sample values are `0010001010`  = `0x08A` and `0100100010` = `0x122`. (Unless the OP thinks the values are LSB first.) The `0x` prefix indicates a hexadecimal, not binary value,